# How do you add connection options to PSQL?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Some Postgres connection options are usually specified in the connection string. For example, `sslmode=require` can be set with the following connection string

```sh
postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres?sslmode=require
```

But `psql --help` doesn't provide any information on how to set something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in a *conninfo* string or URI. The two examples below are equivalent.

```sh
psql postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres?sslmode=require
psql "sslmode=require" -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 -d postgres
```

Multiple options are space delineated.

```
psql "dbname=postgres sslmode=require" -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432
```

See The Connection URI [Parameter Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) documentation for other options.

You can also inspect the current connection info using the [\conninfo](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) meta command

```sh
postgres=# \conninfo
You are connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres" on host "localhost" at port "5432".
```

The online documentation of `psql` goes into more detail under the
[Connecting to a Database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-psql.html#R2-APP-PSQL-CONNECTING) section.